# Configure Eclipse logging for Exceptions and Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

Is there a good way, either by configuring the built-in console or using a plugin, to configure and filter the logging output for Exceptions and Errors and their stacktraces in Eclipse?

I'd like to have the option to do either of the following

- Do not log anything when Exceptions/Errors of type X are thrown
- only log the first 1/2/3... lines of the stacktrace when Exceptions/Errors of type X are thrown

The dialog I get to from `Right Click > Preferences` in the console on Eclipse Kepler does not offer either of the above.